# Prove that there exist $2015$ consecutive abundant numbers

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

A positive integer $N$ is called abundant if the sum of its divisors is 
greater than $N$: $\delta (N) >N$.

My question is:

> Prove that there exists an integer: $k\in\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$ such that the numbers $k+1,k+2,k+3,......,k+2015$ are all abundant.

Comment: I made some edition to my question

Comment: ok, thank you for this note, i edited it .

Comment: I think now it's clear question

Comment: I deleted it , mayeb if i prove the first i can do the second

Comment: not all values of k are availaibe but just to investigate for K that's verifie the claim .

Comment: and pleas read well the question, I'm sure that's hard problem

Comment: @barto, thank you very much for your edition to my question

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Key idea:** Construct $2015$ pairwise coprime abundant numbers to conclude the existence of $2015$ *consecutive* abundant numbers using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Let $I(n)=\frac{\sigma(n)}n$ denote the abundancy index of $n$; if $n=\prod p_k^{a_k}$ we have $I(n)=\prod\frac{p_k-p_k^{-a_k}}{p_k-1}$.

Let $p_n$ denote the $n$th prime and $P_n=\prod_{k\leq n} p_k$, with $I(P_n)=\prod_{k\leq n}\frac{p_k-p_k^{-1}}{p_k-1}$. Observe $\frac{p_k-p_k^{-1}}{p_k-1}=1+\frac{1-p_k^{-1}}{p_k-1}\geq1+\frac1{2(p_k-1)}$.

Because $\sum_{k\geq0}\frac 1{p_k}$ diverges, so does $\sum\frac 1{p_k-1}$ and hence $I(P_n)\to\infty$. This means we can find $n_1,n_2,\ldots$ such that $I(\frac{P_{n_{k+1}}}{P_{n_k}})>2$ for all $k\geq1$.
Because the numbers $Q_k=\frac{P_{n_{k+1}}}{P_{n_k}}$ are pairwise coprime, we can find $N$ such that
$$\left\{\begin{array}l
N\equiv-1\pmod{Q_1}\\
N\equiv-2\pmod{Q_2}\\
\;\;\;\;\;\vdots\\
N\equiv-2015\pmod{Q_{2015}}
\end{array}\right.$$

by CRT.

Because a multiple of an abundant number is itself abundant (in general we have $I(a)<I(b)$ if $a\mid b$), this means that $N+1,\ldots,N+2015$ are all abundant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, since the question answered i don't know why the downvote to my question .

Comment: The tendency in this forum is to demand "work". I am not happy about this either.

Comment: As you say, it is no more than a 'tendency'. The rule is to provide context, which can, but need not be, work - as far as I am informed of the latest discussions. I'm here mainly for having fun and don't think it is ever harmful to _answer_ a question as canonical as this one.

Comment: @barto, do you meant this question is not appropriat for SEM?

Comment: The question is ok; in fact I think it's the kind of questions we want because the existence of arbitrary large sequences of consecutive abundant numbers is a very natural question to ask. (The question is said to be more or less _canonical_.) The reason why it isn't that well-received is because it lacks context (which can be either mentioning the source of the question, your thoughts, an estimate of its difficulty, some background in case it is part of a problem set in some course or book, why you find it interesting, etc...

Comment: ... or even a motivation why you are not giving any more context - in this case perhaps because it is a natural question to ask.) Some people here just don't want to feel as if they're working in a factory, answering every question that is given to them - so do I.

Comment: @barto, thank you very much for those info, i forget to put the source of question .